# Jupyter notebook new cell has more than one line

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I just installed Anaconda Python on a Kubuntu 15.10 machine.

Using Mozilla Firefox, I have encountered one annoying problem. Each time I add a new cell, instead of a single-line cell, the new cell has multiple lines and consequently takes up quite some space. I cannot make it smaller.

It's a minor problem but still quite annoying. How can I fix this?

I attached a screen shot of a new notebook to illustrate.[image]

Comment: have you tried chrome or other browser?Does it happens?

Comment: Hi I use Anaconda with Firefox on my Windows machine and don't have such problems, so I didn't think about trying another browser. I'll try Chrome and report the result.

Comment: Thanks it's alright on Chrome! Guess I have to reinstall Firefox to see whether it solves the problem. Chrome runs really slow on my poor machine..

Answer (score 0):

Likely a problem with your browser. Try another. Everything works fine for me in Google Chrome.